# Разный размер текста в одном TextView с условием (Ответ найден)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

Как сделать условие поиска символов в строке String и изменить их размер?

Например:

Есть строка: "Деньги приходят и уходят, и уходят, и уходят..."

Как сделать условие чтобы все слова "уходят", стали в 2 раза больше?

Нашел один ответ, но никак не получается его использовать...

Компилятор ругается на оператор Utils..

Помогите пожалуйста! Заранее благодарю!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всмысле ругается на Utils? Utils это просто класс автора, по всей видимости, из которого вызываются эти методы.

Comment: Щас попробовал исправить и вот что вышло: если символы заданные в условии есть, то тогда только первый символ в строке изменяется а остальные нет, а если символа заданного в условии нету, то вылетает ошибка.. Мне надо чтобы везде где есть совпадение символов менялось..

Comment: Да, потому что startIndexOfPath хранит в себе стартовый индекс первого попавшего слова. Вам надо получить циклом все индексы и уже для все слов выставлять span. Что касается вылета из-за незаданного символа, то вначале метода напишите типа if(path.lenght() == 0) return;

Comment: Помогите написать этот цикл пожалуйста, а то я не совсем понимаю как правильно это сделать..

Comment: Я использую html верстку, и подставляю ее в TextView при помощи Html.fromHtml

Comment: У меня приложение сборник с возможностью редактирования песен, если сделать при помощи html верстки, то что будет если песню захотят отредактировать обычные пользователи??

Comment: Мне нужен универсальный код который будет работать на все песни, т.е. условие которое будет искать заданный набор символов и изменять их как мне нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем просидел 2 часа и нашел 2 решения данного вопроса:

1: Если требуется изменить размер 1 символа или слова

```
String text="Деньги приходят и уходят, и уходят, и уходят...";
Spannable span1 = new SpannableString(text);
Spannable span2 = new SpannableString(text);
String path="уходят";
int startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path);


while (startIndexOfPath!=-1) {
    span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan((int) textView.getTextSize()*2), 
    startIndexOfPath, startIndexOfPath + path.length(), 0);
    StringBuilder sTextBuilder = new StringBuilder(span2);
    sTextBuilder.replace(startIndexOfPath,startIndexOfPath+path.leght(),"0");
    span2=new SpannableString(sTextBuilder);
    startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path);
}

textView.setText(span1);
```

Создаем переменную text типа `String` и присваиваем ей наш текст:

Создаем 2 переменные `Spanable` и присваиваем им переменную text дальше объясню почему именно 2

Создаем переменную path типа `String` и вносим в неё символ или строку которую хотим изменить

Создаем переменную startIndexOfPath типа `int` и присваиваем ей индекс указанного символа в переменной path из переменной span2

Создаем цикл который будет срабатывать если в тексте есть указанный нами символ в переменной path

**** Начало цикла ****

Изменяем размер указанного нами символа в тексте (span1). Я получаю размер шрифта из `TextView` и умножаю его на 2

В функции AbsoluteSizeSpan можно указывать только точный размер типа `int` (в пикселях)

Создаем переменную `StringBuilder` и присваиваем ей переменную span2

Заменяем в переменной span2 найденный(е) символ(ы) на любые другие на такое же кол-во как мы указали в переменной path. Это нужно для того чтобы если в тексте повторяются указанные нами символы, программа заменяла их всех а не только 1.

Присваиваем переменной span2 измененный текст

Снова присваиваем переменной startIndexOfPath индекс указанного символа в переменной path из уже измененной переменной span2

**** Конец цикла ****

Присваиваем `TextView` переменную span1

2 переменных `Spannable` нужны для того чтобы в первой переменной изменять размер символов которые нам нужны, а во второй мы производим поиск этих символов.

2: Если требуется изменить размер целой строки

```
String text="любой текст";
Spannable span1 = new SpannableString(text);
Spannable span2 = new SpannableString(text);
String path1="символ указывающий начало строки";
String path2="символ указывающий конец строки"
int startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path1);
int endIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path2);

while (startIndexOfPath!=-1) {
    span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan((int) textView.getTextSize()*2), 
    startIndexOfPath, endIndexOfPath, 0);
    StringBuilder sTextBuilder = new StringBuilder(span2);
    sTextBuilder.replace(startIndexOfPath,endIndexOfPath,"0");
    span2=new SpannableString(sTextBuilder);
    startIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path1);
    endIndexOfPath = span2.toString().indexOf(path2);
}

textView.setText(span1);
```

Здесь всё тоже самое только вместо одного символа мы изменяем целую строку, думаю что исходя из первого примера тут все понятно

Спасибо за внимание =)